# How to get the array of the triangles, the 3D object is build from?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I would like to get the array of the triangles, but I can't find it in the geometry object.

---

.faces aren't triangles. If I create a cube, then a face looks like this:

```
"faces": [{
    "a": 0,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 1,
    ...
```

These are polygons, not faces.
[image: faces]

Comment: "These are polygons, not faces" - umm, faces == polygons

Comment: I could see an alternative definition where a 'face' was defined as 'coplanar polygons'. As someone who worked in modelling in both the game development and thermal modelling sector, I can tell you that for the most part, faces and polygons are interchangeable terms. It would appear that the authors of three.js agrees with this assessment as well, judging by the terms used in his documentation.

Comment: Then how to get the triangles of a face, if it contains more than 3 vertices?

Comment: That is a more advanced question, but the real question is why do you want to get the tris? Whoever pushed the quad on to your object instead of the corresponding tris must have had a reason to do it.

Comment: I updated my answer to address the quad to tri problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you push a `Face4` into `faces`, then you're going to end up with a quad when calling faces. If you're pushing `Face3` into `faces` then you'll get a triangle back. If you're getting a `d` on a `faces` call, you pushed a `Face4`.

If you're asking how to get tris from a quad, that's a different question.

Basically, knowing that the 'order' of the quad is `A B C D` you can generally say that `A B C` and `A C D` are triangles that will share the approximate normal of the quad. (I saw approximate because the quad may be slightly skewed. The less co-planar the points are, the more the skew will be apparent, and the more difference the normals will have.)

Now, there are other combinations that will work. The easiest way to do it is to draw out `A B C D` on some paper, and note the direction (Clockwise or Counterclockwise). As long as your tris are also that same direction (which ever it was) then you'll be just fine. Clearly, if `A B C` is a valid tri, then so would `B C A` and `C A B`. The same goes for `A C D` being `C D A` and `D A C`. But you could split it across the other diagonal if you wanted as well, and form `A B D` and `B C D`. Following the previous logic you create the other identical triangles for those.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that the job of ".faces" ? See [here](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/49/#Geometry).